# A physical algorithm that finds all integer partitions of a number

Tags: algorithms, education, integer-partitions

If this is not the right forum for this question let me know.

I am looking for a `physical algorithm` that can be easily followed by anyone not knowing much mathematics to get integer partitions of a number.

I have come up with the following way - but there is an issue (described later).

Suppose I want to [divide number 11 into all its integer partitions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer%20partition%20%20of%2011) (order is not important).

For finding `partitions of size 2` we do following.

Take 11 coins of identical widths. Take a paper. Write `1` and `2` on it

```
1    2
```

Below the first number, keep all 11 coins one upon another to make a tower of height `11`. This is represented as -

```
1      2

11c   0c
```

Now, shift `1` coin from first column to second column.

```
1      2

10c   1c
```

Here, height of tower 1 = 10, height of tower2 = 1

Keep on doing this, only if `Height of tower 1 >= Height of tower2`

On each step of the algorithm, we get new integer partition.

- This "physical algorithm" is easy to understand by anyone knowing
  basic mathematics.
- Preferrably, each step in the physical algorithm must show a new
  partitioning way.
- There should be an end condition to the algorithm.
- When the algorithm reaches end condition, all possible partitioning
  ways must have been shown.

If we now want to find [all partitions of size 3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer%20partition%20%20of%2011%20of%20size%203), the problem gets a bit tricky.

We have 3 towers, with following restrictions 
`Height of tower 1 >= Height of tower2 >= Height of tower3`

But thing is, there are certain positions, from which we cannot go to next stage without destroying earlier stage - what do I mean by this? See below

`Step1`

```
1      2     3

9c    1c     1c
```

`Step2`

```
1      2     3

8c    2c     1c
```

`Step3`

```
1      2     3

7c    3c     1c
```

`Alternative Step3`

```
1      2     3

7c    2c     2c
```

At `step 3` the algorithm creates two branches - people could either put new coin in tower2 or tower1. **How should the algorithm statements be written so that by the time the algorithm is finished, all partitions of size 3 are known?**

**If you could come up with a new algorithm, that's welcome too!**

Comment: I don't get the question. The next recursive algorithm could be used : Given a number $n$ - take $1$ and solve for $n-1$, with a lower bound on the size of coin ($1$), or take $2$ and solve for $n-2$, with a lower bound $2$, etc. If you are too inclined output all the coins when left with 0. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @dEmigOd what do you mean by solve for $n-1$? Could you give an example demonstration of this algo?

Comment: There are a couple algorithms discussed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.2331.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "physical algorithm", but the way you describe yours, it sounds as if you mean pretty much the same thing as what is conventionally referred to as an "algorithm". There are algorithms for generating all partitions in [Pre-fascicle 3B of The Art of Computer Programming](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc3b.pdf) by Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with following algorithm for finding partitions of size 3. It may be generalized to size `N`, but I'm not 100% sure.

**Initial Setup**

A paper with 3 numbers, 1,2 and 3 written on it.

11 coins.

1 coin in tower1, 1 coin in tower2, 9 coins in tower3.

This is represented as

```
[step1] 1 1 9
```

**Algorithm**
This algorithm is a series of steps. Some of the steps are termed "starting positions". Once a starting position is reached, an operation `O1` must be performed to reach next step - while satisfying a certain condition `C0`. Then we repeat that operation multiple times. If that partular condition `C0` cannot be satisfied, we go to the next starting position via operaiton `O2`.

`Condition C0` = **Height of tower1 <= Height of tower2 <= Height of tower3**

`Operation O1` = **Shift one coin from last tower to second-last tower while `condition C0` is satisfied. If `C0` cannot be satisfied do operation `O2`**

`Operation O2` = **Shift one coin from last tower to first tower. Then shift coins from second-last tower to last-tower until
`Height of tower1 = Height of tower2`**

`Termination condition` = **If after performing `operation O2`, `condition C0` cannot be satisfied, algorithm is terminated and that coin distribution is discarded.**

**Algorithm demonstration**

**Initial Starting position**

```
[step1] 1 1 9
```

`Condition C0`
`Height of tower1 <= Height of tower2 <= Height of tower3`

`Operation O1` -> Shift one coin from last tower to second-last tower while `condition C0` is satisfied.

```
[step2] 1 2 8
[step3] 1 3 7
[step4] 1 4 6
[step5] 1 5 5
```

Now, we can no longer perform `operation O1` without disobeying `condition C0`. So we shift to next starting position via `operation O2` which modifies coin distribution according to some conditions.

`Operation O2` - 
Shift one coin from last tower to first tower
Shift coins from second-last tower to last-tower until
`Height of tower1 = Height of tower2`

**If `condition C0` cannot be satisfied at this stage - algorithm is terminated. Otherwise we go forward as below**

After performing `operation O2` we reach next starting position as below

```
[step6] 2 2 7
```

Now, a series of `O1` operations takes us through -

```
[step7] 2 3 6
[step8] 2 4 5
```

Now `C0` cannot be obeyed after performing `operation O1`, so we apply `operation O2`

```
[step9] 3 3 5
```

Then another `O1`

```
[step10] 3 4 4
```

Now `C0` cannot be obeyed after performing `O1`, so we apply `O2`

```
4 4 3
```

**`C0` cannot be obeyed by above distribution, so algorithm has terminated and last coin position `4 4 3` is discarded.**

Thus we get all 10 ways to partition 11 into 3 summands.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a short C program for you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int CountIntDecompositions(int n, int lower_bound, int coins[], int coinIndex)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return -1;

    if (n == 0)
    {
        printf("(%d%", coins[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < coinIndex; ++i)
            printf(", %d", coins[i]);
        printf(")\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int numWays = 0;
    for (int coin = lower_bound; coin <= n; ++coin)
    {
        coins[coinIndex] = coin;
        int ways = CountIntDecompositions(n - coin, coin, coins, coinIndex + 1);
        if (ways != -1)
            numWays += ways;
    }

    return numWays;
}

int main()
{
    int coins[11] = { 0 };
    int numWays = CountIntDecompositions(11, 1, coins, 0);
    printf("Total num of ways %d\n", numWays);
    return 0;
}
```

You can call it a physical algorithm, it prints out every possible way of integer decomposition - once.

The algorithm gradually increases the next lowest int value to pick. I've used "coins" as i think initially i was used to change. You can generalize to only available integer values (instead of increasing coin value by 1, you proceed to next available value)